# Pb. DataGrid.Items while enabeling the Paging

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using a Datagrid with paginig, while clicking on select all , all items in all pages are selected but while the execution, I'ven't all the selected items.
How can you get the DataGrid.Items.Count to reflect the FULL record count instead of displaying the page size?

I'm using this property and all it's displaying is the page size of 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was:

((DataSet)DataGrid.DataSource).Tables[0].Rows.Count

Answer (score 0):

You could just do `DataGrid.DataSource.Count`.

Comment: Thanks Shaharyar! for you answer, but it is not exactly